# jquery datepicker not focussed after date is chosen, after postback datepicker doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, jquery

everytime the user selects a date from my datepicker the for some reason instead of staying focused on the are the date picker is in it scrolls to the top of the page.

Heres the function located at the bottom of my asp.net page under the

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#<%= pissued1.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

This is the code.

```
<td align="left" colspan="2">
    <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="labdi1" runat="server" Text="*Date Issued:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="p1divalidate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pissued1"
        ErrorMessage="You Forgot The">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        </strong>
    <asp:TextBox ID="pissued1" runat="server" Width="45%"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

and also on postback my datepickers stop working. For example i have a dropdownlist that causes postback and if the user uses the drop downlist then the datepickers stop working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're page is done loading before your datepicker() is initialized...Putting it at the bottom of the page kind of works, but I've stopped that myself personally and switched to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
   function(){
     $( "#<%= pissued1.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
}
);
</script>
```

my answer is not much, but it assures the page is done screwing around before your datepicker is started up.